# $.Post 404 Error with parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working on the below `ajax` call in my MVC application which isn't working(the controller is not getting called) when `parameter` is used.
Works well when i remove the parameter in both `ajax` call and `controller`.

//Code:

```
 $('#btnGw').click(function (e) {             

                $.post("../api/cuews/", {  openId: "3" }, function (data) {

                    // data to manipulate for filter values

                });              

            });
```

//Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public string Post(string openId)
    {
        string json = openId;

        return json;
    }
```

Tried adding Json.Stringify,

```
$.post("../api/cuews/", {  openId: Json.Stringify("3") }, function (data) {

                    // data to manipulate for filter values

                });
```

and

```
$.post("../api/cuews/", Json.Stringify({ openId: "3" }), function (data) {

                    // data to manipulate for filter values

                });
```

But the result is same.

**Error:**(In console)

```
POST http://localhost/api/cuews/ 404 (Not Found)
```

What am i doing wrong with the parameters?

FYI,

The same structure works for `$.get` with parameters.

Comment: Since you're getting a 404 I'm not convinced that your API call address is correct - what does your controller and routing look like?

Comment: @KallumTanton I'm wondering it works for `$.get()`.

Comment: Which jQuery method works for GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

1. Create a model with required properties.
2. Pass the model as a param
3. Make sure the param passed from AJAX is same(TEXT) as what is in Model.

Eg:

```
 public class TestModel
 {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Desc { get;set; }
 }

 $.ajax({
     url: '../api/Test/',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: JSON.stringify({ Id: "1", Desc : "Name" }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data) {
                  alert("Success!!!")
              },
     error: function (xhrequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error")
              }
 });
```

AJAX works well when the params in these state. Just an work around.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you send parameter using $_POST and your `public string Post(string openId)` is requesting parameter to be passed in `$_GET`. Try moving this parameter assignment to inside of function.

Comment: I have updated the ques. Do you say that? If yes, then its the same. Didn't work

Comment: The controller parameters seem fine - OP has used the `HttpPost` decorator correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try :

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",//type of data to be send
                    url:   youraddressgoeshere
                    dataType: "json",//type of data to be received
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),//data to be send
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                         //some code
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {    
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
       });
```

You are converting JSON.stringify on value and not on the whole object. Try converting the whole object and pass it to your serverside method.

Also,

if you are working on ASP.NET MVC go to RouteConfig in App_Start folder and check how you have defined the url

**FOR EX:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

notice `{controller}/{action}/{id}`  here I have {id} for parameters. Therefore if I were you I would try changing `public string Post(string openId)` to `public string Post(string id)` in the server side controller method.

Comment: @Justinas I was editing the answer with explanation. If only you had waited a little longer before downvoting.

Comment: @Arbaaz See my second option that i tried with the same. Still it didn't work.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar are you using asp.net MVC?

Comment: @Arbaaz Yep. Let me add that in ques. Thanks

Comment: @Arbaaz this is an ajax call and just defining a general route config is enough. Also i have few other post method which works well too.